# Numerical rounding errors in intersection code

Tags: geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

I hope this question is in the right place, as it is as much about programming as it is about math.
I'm trying to find the intersection between a circle and a line. My implementation of the algorithm works fine, until the line segment becomes very short.
Take for example the following circle:
center (-0.0177,0.0098)
radius 0.00985
and line:
position (-0.0275498730956292,0.00985)
length 1.269043708E-7
direction (-1,0)

My algorithm (based on https://github.com/jpkinney/meshmorph/blob/master/doc/IntersectionLine2Circle2.pdf):

```
PGVector DELTA=PGVectorSubtract(line.position, arc.center);
CGFloat DDELTA=PGVectorDotProd(line.direction, DELTA);
CGFloat lengthDELTA2=PGVectorDotProd(DELTA, DELTA);
CGFloat delta=DDELTA*DDELTA-(lengthDELTA2-arc.radius*arc.radius);

if (CGFloatIsSmallerThanZero(delta)) return PGIntersectionNone;
else if (CGFloatIsBiggerThanZero(delta)) {
    CGFloat c,d;
    c=(-DDELTA-sqrt(delta))/line.length;
    d=(-DDELTA+sqrt(delta))/line.length;
    return PGIntersecionMultiple;
} else {
    *s1=-DDELTA/line.length;
    return PGIntersectionSingle;
}
```

It calculates that d=1,3669532933245911E-11. It should be zero...
My float compare functions use 1000*DBL_EPSILON as its thresholds.

I've already solved some of these problems by storing the line direction separate from its length., so the delta calculation is more reliable. But it seems the problem has only shifted.

How do I solve problems like these?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Remco Poelstra

Comment: The rounding problem amounts to how finely we can tell whether a point is inside the circle or not.  For this purpose it is usually best to translate the circle and potentially intersecting line segment so that the circle is centered at the origin.

Comment: See Jonathan Shewchuk's page http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html for robust algorithms to 'in-circle' problems. And computing dot products can be tricky too, see 
T. Ogita, S.M. Rump, and S. Oishi, Accurate sum and dot product,
SIAM J. Sci. Comput., 26 (2005), pp. 1955-1988. Available 
from http://www.ti3.tu-harburg.de/paper/rump/OgRuOi05.pdf

Comment: Also double is preferrable to float (if `CGFloat` actually represents a `double` then don't mind). For a `float` the result is mostly indistinguishable from `0`. What do you want to apply this to? In most cases you can chose a rather high threshold (for games e.g.)...

Comment: @AlexR `CGFLoat` is a double on 64bit machines indeed. But using doubles only delays any problems I think. I use it to calculate polygons (consisting of lines and arcs) for PCB CAD/CAM. So some accuracy is needed.

Comment: @gammatester These links look highly interesting. I hope they allow me to improve my code.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate the knowledge of the second paper of @gammatester and found out that the first 4 lines happen to be calculated exact (for doubles). The problem is with the calculation of d, where the numerator is noise (smaller than epsilon), divided by a small number resulting in big noise (bigger than epsilon). Would it be an acceptable solution to check the numerator for equality with zero? Or would I then be better of implementing everything in fixed point arithmetic?